# Azure Notification Hub quota limits

Tags: azure, azure-notificationhub

The notification hub [REST API documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223269.aspx) mentions a quota for notification hubs in a given namespace. I couldn't find on the documentation nor the [pricing page](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) what are the boundaries for the quota for each plan.

Empirically, i now know that on the free/basic tier the limit is 100 notification hubs per namespace.

> The maximum number of resources of type NotificationHub has been reached or exceeded. Actual: 100, Max allowed: 100.

Can the quotas be raised? What are the costs?

My current system uses hubs for multitenancy and before jumping to refactor the architecture are there any limits not mentioned on the pricing page?

- Do service bus have quotas on the number of namespaces?
- Do registrations (devices) have quotas/rate limit for each notification hub?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Send operations:**

- To increase quotas and start using some advanced features you could
  go https://manage.windowsazure.com, then pick any your Notification
  Hub and set Basic or Standard pricing tire on the Scale tab. Basic is
  $10 per month, Standard - $200. Note that pricing tire is actually
  changed on namespace level and all quotas are enforced against
  namespace.
- Also if you try to call Send operations in parallel from several
  senders then you would see that bandwidth is wider because requests
  are very likely to be routed to different nodes.
- Also if you are going to send a really big volume of notifications
  and each notification is targeted to 1 or very few devices, then
  write to support asking to enable Inbox for your namespace.

**Other quotas:**

- At most 100 (by my best knowledge) namespaces per regular subscription, you can upgrade it to premium with no limit by writing to support.
- At most 100 hubs per namespace, you can increase it by writing to support.
- Number of devices is not actually limited, even for Free tire '500 active devices' limitation is not enforced... for now :)
- Registration rate is limited, quotas start from 2000 per namespace per minute and depends on pricing tire.

**Also:**
Some official pricing details: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/

Comment: The quota increase, by writing to support, is possible with only a basic/standard plan? Or a Support plan [1] is needed?

[1] http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/plans/

Comment: Yes, for MOST of things quota is just mater of pricing tire. But to increase number of namespaces per subscription or number of notification hubs per namespace you have only option contact support. Also if for some reasons you feel like ANY quota does not allow your application to scale enough then it is discussable, sometimes it is possible to find better usage pattern and troubles are gone.

Comment: I dono why this has not been moved to the new portal yet. I just spend a week debugging my code. Eventually to find that on the old portal it said my registration quota has been reached.